# Can a Solartube be installed in a garden shed?

Tags: lighting, shed, workshop

Can a Solar tube be installed in a "Tuff Shed" , used as a workshop? There is no drywall ceiling- just a plywood roof covered with shingles, tar paper, etc. The height of the shed is about 10 ft.

Comment: The primary purpose of a Solar tube is to "transport" or "duct" sunlight to areas otherwise inaccessible. If you have but a roof, would not the solution be a skylight alone?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do that (by cutting the tube or having it project like a smoke stack) but why buy an expensive, long solar tube when, for a fraction of the cost, one could get a shed skylight that would sit flush with the ceiling and have the added benefit of the integrated vents such things can have?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you will have to support the tube length just like it was in a house. And possibly add a small piece of drywall or OSB for it to terminate into. This part depends on how the trim ring attaches to the end of the tube.